# Can't get my IIS website online

Tags: asp.net, iis, ip, lan

I just tried to publish my website via IIS.
I forwarded the right ports to my LAN and it successfully connects to the LAN, but can't connect the internet.
When using 192.168.1.20:8080 (which is my local IP address), it connects to the website, but when using my external IP address it doesn't work.
What do I do wrong?
Thanks!

Comment: This is more of a [_networking_ question](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/). Try doing that from _outside_ your LAN. It's been some time for me so I'll guess - do you properly route traffic that loops back to your LAN (to attempt using external IP)?

Comment: It likely has something to do with the port being auto-blocked by your Windows firewall or :80 not being routed to :8080 in your router.

Comment: Thanks Josh, that was it! The firewall! Thank you very much!

Comment: @user3623819 Made an answer so it can be marked, so the question falls off the feed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It likely has something to do with the port being auto-blocked by your Windows firewall or :80 not being routed to :8080 in your router.

I had this issue too, Windows Firewall's default was to block the :80 port.  I just had to go in and make an exception.

Answer (score 0):

-first of all you should have a static IP address.

-second make sure you add the  make sure you add that IP address to your Network (NIC) card Interface and I hope it will work fine.

[Check This Please](http://oclc.org/support/services/ezproxy/documentation/technote/2w.en.html) or [this topics](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/set-up-multiple-network-interfaces-in-windows-xp/)